# How to setup Replication or Federation between MySQL and Derby?

Tags: mysql, derby, database-replication, federated-table

Perhaps this is not possible yet, but...

What's the easiest way to setup Replication or Federation between MySQL and Derby?

I need a way for data updates/inserts/deletes into a certain table in Derby to automatically flow into an equivalent identical table in MySQL, as quickly and efficiently as possible.

This can be done in application code of course, but it would be inelegant, slow, and inefficient to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I imagine it shouldn't bee to hard using either [c-jdbc](http://c-jdbc.ow2.org/), sequoia or [tungsten](http://www.continuent.com/community/lab-projects/sequoia) (sequoia's successor).

For example, from the c-jdbc home page:
" C-JDBC is an open source (LGPL) database cluster middleware that allows any Java application to transparently access a cluster of databases through JDBC(tm). The database is distributed and replicated among several nodes and C-JDBC balances the queries among these nodes. C-JDBC handles node failures and provides support for checkpointing and hot recovery."

Short feature overview:

- No modification of existing applications or databases,
- High availability provided by advanced RAIDb technology,
- Performance scalability with unique load balancing and query result caching features,
- Integrated JMX-based administration and monitoring,
- 100% Java implementation allowing portability across platforms,
- Open source licensed under LGPL.

It does more than you need, but should cover your use case.